# Calling QFieldSync Plugin from QGIS Py Console

Tags: qfield, qfieldsync

I would like to find way how to call plugin QFieldSync from Python console in QGIS.

Comment: What do you mean by "call"? Opening QFieldSync plugin window or do the all job without opening the plugin window from Python Console?

Comment: What have you tried so far and what were the results?

Answer (score 2):

To open plugin GUI various dialog, you can try

```py
from qgis import utils

qfieldsync_instance = utils.plugins.get('qfieldsync')

# Each below statements open a dialog box
qfieldsync_instance.show_synchronize_dialog()
qfieldsync_instance.show_project_configuration_dialog()
qfieldsync_instance.show_package_dialog()
qfieldsync_instance.show_preferences_dialog()
```

To use Package for QField without GUI, you can't simply use method `package_project` from "Create" button from the plugin instance as it's tied to GUI dialog (try `utils.plugins.get('qfieldsync').push_dlg.package_project()` to see it fail).

Instead, you can do the following

```
from qfieldsync.core import OfflineConverter

canvas = iface.mapCanvas()
project = QgsProject.instance()
offline_editing= True
export_folder = '/path/to/folder'

offline_convertor = OfflineConverter(project, export_folder, canvas.extent(), offline_editing)
offline_convertor.convert()
```